# Whats wrong with the last line of this code?

Tags: php, html

This is the code the last line to close the php has an error that I cant seem to find. The code is for my university project. The opening php bracket is fine but on line 27 there seems to be an  error in the code itself.

```
<?php
include_once 'ShapeClass.php';

class Circle extends Shape
{
    private $radius;

    function __construct($n,$c,$r)
{
    parent::__construct($n,$c);
    $this->radius = $r;
}


public function area()
{
    return ( pi()*$this->radius * $this->radius);
}

public function perimeter()
{
    return ( 2 * pi() * $this->radius);
}

public function compareParameters($s)
    {
    case "Circle":
    }
        {if ($this->radius > $r->radius)
            {
                print "<h2>This circle's radius is bigger</h2>";
            }
         else
            {
                print "<h2>This circle's radius is not bigger</h2>";
            }
        break;
        }
    case "Square":
        {if ($this->radius > $s->side)
            {
                print "<h2>This circle's radius is bigger than the square's side</h2>";
            }
         else
            {
                print "<h2>This circle's radius is not bigger than the square's side</h2>" ;
            }
        break;
        }
    case "Rectangle":
        {if ($this->radius > $w->width)
            {
                print "<h2>This circle's radius is bigger then the rectangle's width</h2>";
            }
         else
            {
                print "<h2>This circle's radius is not bigger than the rectangle's width</h2>" ;
            }
        break;
        }
    case "Rectangle":
        {if ($this->radius > $h->height)
            {
                print "<h2>This circle's radius is bigger than the rectangle's height</h2>";
            }
         else
            {
                print "<h2>This circle's radius is not bigger than the rectangle's height</h2>";
            }
        break;
        }
    case "Triangle":
        {if ($this->radius > $b->base)
            {
                print "<h2>This circle's radius is bigger than the triangle's base</h2>";
            }
         else
            {
                print "<h2>This circle's radius is not bigger than the triangle's base</h2>" ;
            }
        break;
        }
    case "Triangle":
        {if ($this->radius > $ha->height)
            {
                print "<h2>This circle's radius is bigger than the triangle's height</h2>";
            }
         else
            {
                print "<h2>This circles radius is not bigger than the triangle's height</h2>";
            }
        break;
        }   
    case "Triangle":
        {if ($this->radius > $hb->hypotenuse)
            {
                print "<h2>This circle's radius is bigger than the triangle's hypotenuse</h2>";
            }
         else
            {
                print "<h2>This circle's radius is not bigger than the triangle's hypotenuse</h2>" ;
            }
        break;
        }
    case "Parallelogram":
        {if ($this->radius > $sb->sidebase)
            {
                print "<h2>This circle's radius is bigger than the parallelogram's base</h2>";
            }
         else
            {
                print "<h2>This circle's radius is not bigger than the parallelogram's base</h2>";
            }
        break;
        }
    case "Parallelogram":   
        {if ($this->radius > $sh->sideheight)
            {
                print "<h2>This circle's radius is bigger than the parallelogram's height</h2>";
            }
         else
            {
                print "<h2>This circle's radius is not bigger than the parallelogram's height</h2>";
            }
        break;
                }
?>
```

Comment: Recommend reading [PHP Control Structures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php).  Or, [Language Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php).  How did you come up with this code?

Comment: You've failed to explain what error you're receiving, or think you're receiving.

Answer (score 2):

You have case `case` statements without a `switch` around them.

Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

It should look a bit like:

```
switch (...) {
    case "..." {
        ...
        break;
    }
    case "..." {
        ...
        break;
    }
    case "..." {
        ...
        break;
    }
    case "..." {
        ...
        break;
    }
    default: {
        ...
        break;
    }
}
```

The `{}` in the `case`/`default` statements are optional.
The `default` statement is optional too.

Comment: @user3427523 I did do an edit to my answer. But if you want more explanation, please tell me what you don't understand... Have you followed the link and read it?